# Server bandwidth is going crazy, after reboot all ok

Tags: ubuntu, bandwidth, optimization, streaming

I have a streaming server with 10gbps card on it. I'm using ~2.5gbps.

My server is running perfect for 8-9 hours / day, and after that is going crazy, and everyone is freezing. At exactly the same time i reboot the system , and everything is back to normal.

I have monitor connections , bandwidth output everything. From 2.5 gbps, after 8-9 hourrs it goes to 1gbps thats why everyone is freezing, but after a reboot everything back to normal.

Anyone has any explanation about this?

This is my sysctl config

```
net.core.somaxconn = 65535
net.ipv4.route.flush=1
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save=1
net.ipv4.tcp_moderate_rcvbuf = 1
fs.file-max = 6815744
fs.aio-max-nr = 6815744
fs.nr_open = 6815744
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65000
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 10000000 10000000 10000000
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 10000000 10000000 10000000
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 10000000 10000000 10000000
net.core.rmem_max = 524287
net.core.wmem_max = 524287
net.core.rmem_default = 524287
net.core.wmem_default = 524287
net.core.optmem_max = 524287
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 300000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 300000
vm.swappiness=1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=196608
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
vm.max_map_count = 655300
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
```

The streaming is being done using PHP-FPM & nginx.

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 64bit with stock kernel. I tried the kernel 4.8 same results.

Comment: Check your logs files for more information

Comment: i checked the kern.log and few other logs. Nothing suspicious is written there

Answer (score 0):

throwing a bunch of config options and some random data about your system at us isn't at all useful.

You need to apply scientific method.

- Install monitoring
- Gather data
- Use the data to help understand the system
- Make changes based on what you have learned above
- Monitor changes
- Repeat analysis and make changes as required
- Document changes

It's not rocket engineering or even alternate facts. Simple applied system management principles is all you need.

[Further reading](https://serverfault.com/search?q=user:9517%20scientific%20method)

Answer (score 0):

Your post is somewhat confusing.

> after that is going crazy

Implies increased activity, but you say...

> everyone is freezing

...but then you contradict the assertion that "everyone" is affected by saying

> From 2.5 gbps, after 8-9 hourrs it goes to 1gbps

If you are still sending out 1gbps, then clearly some clients are not affected. You also state:

> The streaming is being done using PHP-FPM & nginx

...in which case it is *not* streaming. HTTP and fastCGI are not  streaming protocols.

Based on the information you have provided, we cannot tell what ios wrong with your server, but a *likely* cause is that the nfconntrack table is full.

> net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=196608

How many buckets are in use?

Its also possible your server is behind a misbehaving router/not receiving congestion notifications.